# New commit on top of earlier commits gets removed -> new work on the earlier commits by others -> revive the removed commit? Pull: divergent branches

Tags: git, commit, push, pull

New commit on top of other commits was removed, new work on the earlier commits from others, how to revive the removed commit? When checking out the last commit before the one that is to be revived, pull fails: divergent branches:

```shell
$ git pull
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint:
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only     # fast-forward only
hint:
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Trying this, taken from [How to Merge when you get error "Hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them." - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72231711/11154841):

```shell
git config pull.rebase false
```

But then, `git pull` still throws:

```
Error:
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Auto-merging xzy/xyz/my_file.xyz
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in xzy/xyz/my_file.xyz
Auto-merging xzy/xyz/my_file.abc
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in xzy/xyz/my_file.abc
```

so I better set it to true again with `git config pull.rebase true`.

What to do to be able to update all of the commits from the branch and then push the removed one back on top?

I could backup my work, hard reset to the commit before, paste the work, and commit the work again. But there should be an easy git way for this. I fear that this is rather a beginner question. My guess is that this can be done with stash/reset/cherry picking from the reflog.

Comment: Sounds like `git rebase`

Comment: @gronostaj You are right. So easy. I had just forgotten about it.